# TypeORM relations and express

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, typeorm

I'm making Many to One, One to many relations with TypeORM and MySQL, and Express. There are two tables cold post and user.
One user has many posts. and each post has one user.
I would like to use 'userUuid' column as a foreign key to join these two tables.
Can anybody tell me how to fix it?

Thank you

// user

```
 import {
        Entity,
        PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
        Column,
        BaseEntity,
        BeforeInsert,
        Generated,
        OneToMany,
        } from 'typeorm'
        import { v4 as uuid } from 'uuid'
    
        import { Post } from './Post'
        @Entity()
        export class User extends BaseEntity {
        @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
        id!: number
      
        @Column()
        userId!: string
      
        @Column()
        @Generated('uuid')
        userUuid!: string
      
        @Column({ nullable: true })
        displayName!: string
        
        @Column({ nullable: true })
        email!: string
      
        @OneToMany(() => Post, (post: Post) => post.user)
        posts!: Post[]
      
        @BeforeInsert()
        createUuid() {
          this.userUuid = uuid()
        }
      
        toJSON() {
          return { ...this, id: undefined }
        }
      }
```

// post

```
 import {
        Entity,
        PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
        CreateDateColumn,
        UpdateDateColumn,
        Column,
        BaseEntity,
        Generated,
        BeforeInsert,
        ManyToOne,
        JoinColumn,
      } from 'typeorm'
      import { v4 as uuid } from 'uuid'
      import { User } from './User'
      @Entity()
      export class Post extends BaseEntity {
        @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
        id!: number
      
        @Column()
        @Generated('uuid')
        postUuid!: string
      
        @Column({ nullable: true })
        userUuid!: string
      
        @CreateDateColumn({ nullable: true })
        createdAt!: Date
      
        @UpdateDateColumn({ nullable: true })
        updatedAt!: Date
      
        @Column({ nullable: true })
        content!: string
      
        @BeforeInsert()
        createUuid() {
          this.postUuid = uuid()
        }
      
        @ManyToOne(() => User, (user: User) => user.posts)
        user!: User
      
        @JoinColumn([{ name: 'userUuid' }, { referencedColumnName: 'userUuid' }])
        toJSON() {
          return { ...this, id: undefined }
        }
      }
```

//express

```
router
  .route('/')
  .get((req: Request, res: Response) => {
    User.find({ relations: ['posts'] })
      .then((data) => {
        res.send(data)
      })
      .catch((err) => res.send(err))
  })
```

//express

```
router
  .route('/')
  .get((req: Request, res: Response) => {
    Post.find({ relations: ['user'] })
      .then((data) => {
        res.send(data)
      })
      .catch((err) => res.send(err))
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you need to use `JoinColumn` decorator.

```js
class Post /*...*/ {
  /*...*/
  @ManyToOne(() => User)
  @JoinColumn({ referencedColumnName: "userUuid" })
  userUuid!: string;
  /*...*/
}
```

---

[From TypeORM docs](https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/relations#joincolumn-options)

> Join columns are always a reference to some other columns (using a foreign key). By default your relation always refers to the primary column of the related entity. If you want to create relation with other columns of the related entity - you can specify them in @JoinColumn as well:

```js
@ManyToOne(type => Category)
@JoinColumn({ referencedColumnName: "name" })
category: Category;
```

> The relation now refers to name of the Category entity, instead of id. Column name for that relation will become categoryName.

Comment: Hi. I used JoinColumn decorator. "@JoinColumn([{ name: 'userUuid' }, { referencedColumnName: 'userUuid' }])" as you can see in my code. It seems a bit tricky to use something like uuid as a foreign key. Maybe it's not a good idea anyway?? 
If I don't refer to another column as a foreign key by using JoinColumn decorator, It works. so I gave up and work the normal way.
Thank you for your advise